# Sum/product of Church-encoded list of numbers does not type check

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, church-encoding

Following standard definitions of Church-encoded natural numbers and lists represented as right folds, I want to write a function that takes a list of numbers as its argument and returns sum of its elements:

```hs
type Number = forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a

type List a = forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b

zero :: Number
zero _ x = x

plus :: Number -> Number -> Number
plus a b f x = a f (b f x)

sum :: List Number -> Number
sum xs = xs plus zero
```

This definition of `sum` does not type check - I assume it's because its type expands to

```hs
(forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a)
```

whereas function definition demands rather

```hs
forall a. ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

and it does, in fact, type check:

```hs
sum :: List ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a  -- OK
sum xs = xs plus' zero
  where
    plus' :: (t1 -> t -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2 -> t) -> t1 -> t2 -> t3  -- inferred by compiler
    plus' a b f x = a f (b f x)
    zero _ x = x
```

Can I somehow avoid copying `(a -> a) -> a -> a` in all my definitions? Resulting types get very long very quickly... I could do

```
type Number a = (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

and place that in type annotations but perhaps I can do something smarter/tricker than that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In versions of GHC with quick-look impredicativity (9.2 and newer), you can make your original `sum` function work just by enabling the `ImpredicativeTypes` extension.

Answer (score 6):

You can isolate your types in `newtype`. This seems to work:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Number = Number {num :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a}

newtype List a = List {lst :: forall b. (a -> b -> b) -> b -> b}

plus :: Number -> Number -> Number
plus a b = Number (\f x -> (num a) f ((num b) f x))

zero :: Number
zero = Number (\_ x -> x)

sum :: List Number -> Number
sum xs = (lst xs) plus zero
```